# Align 2nd column textbox to 1st column textbox with label in Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align my 2nd column textbox to the first one with label in Bootstrap? Here's my current code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="Full Name" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" CssClass="control-label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Alignment problem]

Comment: Either add label with empty text on second input field or use approach mentioned by @Athanasios Kataras

Answer (score 0):

You create two rows:

```
<div class="form-group container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="Full Name" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" CssClass="control-label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still getting the same output. I even tried this on a new test aspx page just to make sure none of my existing containers are changing the result

Comment: I just put &nbsp; inside the empty col-md-6: <div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>.
Output has been fixed but I'm not sure if this is the best way